# Phing работает только с eclipse?

Tags: ide, eclipse

Можно ли интегрировать Phing к примеру в NetBeans? Или использовать вообще без IDE? Например в терминале?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можешь использовать и без IDE, и в терминале и т.д.

под виндой в cmd

```
%PHP% -r "var_dump(__DIR__ );"
```

где %PHP% путь к php-cgi.exe, ключ r сообщает интерпретатору, что далее идет код

конкретно для phing можно например из папки test подключить его bootstrap.php и посмотреть что будет

```
@echo off
CLS && %PHP% "test/bootstrap.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

А вы на сайте [phing.info](http://www.phing.info/) бывали? Посмотрите, как раз по теме ;)

PhpStorm давно уже его [поддерживает](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/phing.html).